# What are $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$ in terms of cylindrical unit vectors $\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}, \hat{z}$?

Tags: calculus, change-of-variable, cylindrical-coordinates

I can find a lot of resources that show the inverse, (expressing cylindrical in terms of of Cartesian) but I just can't find what I want.

My wild guess is : $\hat{i} = -\sin{\theta} \;\hat{\theta} \\ \hat{j}=\cos{\theta}\;\hat{\theta} \\ \hat{z}=\hat{z}$

Comment: This was the first link when I googled "cylindrical coordinates to cartesian": http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CylindricalCoords.aspx

Comment: I love Paul's notes, what I want is certainly not on there.

Comment: If iIm not mistaking, you are asking for an expression of Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ in terms of cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$.  This is a widely available result:  \begin{eqnarray} x &=& r \cos \theta \\ y &=& r \sin \theta\\z&=&z\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. I wanted the cartesian unit vectors in terms of the cylindrical unit vectors, which is what zahbaz supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cartesian $(x,y,z)$ to cylindrical $(\rho,\phi,z)$,

\begin{align}
\hat{x} &= \cos\phi \hat{\rho} - \sin\phi \hat\phi
\\
\hat{y} &= \sin\phi \hat{\rho} + \cos\phi \hat\phi
\\
\hat{z} &= \hat z
\end{align}

From Griffith's Introduction to Electyrodynamics, inside back cover.